# Term for when someone steals and uses your credit card

Tags: single-word-requests

What is it called when :

> Someone steals and uses your credit card, your account is ___ ?

Not hacked, more like another word for vulnerable?

Comment: 'identity theft' or 'my credit card was stolen'

Comment: compromised .. .

Comment: [Compromised](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/compromised) is and adjective that can be used to describe something where a vulnerability has been found and taken advantage of. Like a credit card being stolen.

Comment: "exposed to risk" ... *of cashlessness/poverty :(*

Answer (score 3):

Like the comments say, you could say your account is **[compromised](https://www.google.com/webhp?ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=define%3A%20compromised)**:

> bring into disrepute or danger by indiscreet, foolish, or reckless
>   behavior.
>
> *"situations in which his troops could be compromised"*
>
> cause to become vulnerable or function less effectively.
>
> *"yo-yo dieting can compromise your immune system"*

Comment: I do agree that `compromised` is the intended word (I posted one of the comments), I think you should be posting the adjective definitions instead of the verb definitions, since the OP's example does ask for a word to accompany the noun `account` :)

Comment: @Hank The example implies either an adjective or a passive construction, so the verb definition works just as well here.

Answer (score 1):

Jeopardized meaning "put (someone or something) into a situation in which there is a danger of loss, harm, or failure" according to Google. Also 'credit card fraud'. According to Wikipedia, "Credit card fraud is a wide-ranging term for theft and fraud committed using or involving a payment card, such as a credit card or debit card, as a fraudulent source of funds in a transaction."

Answer (score 0):

> Someone steals and uses your credit card, your account is ***exposed***.

Collins:

> **[exposed](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/exposed)**
>   *adjective*
>
> 3. **susceptible to attack** or criticism; **vulnerable**

businessdictionary.com:

> **[exposed](http://www.businessdictionary.com/definition/exposed.html)**
>   **Open to danger of** damage, harm, or **loss**.

M-W:

> **[exposed](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/exposed)**
>   *adjective*
>   : not protected or covered

Answer (score 0):

Compromised is widely used among the security manufacturers' slogans for example this one by [Cyclonis](https://www.cyclonis.com/products/password-manager/):

> Create complex passwords to help make it more difficult for hackers to **compromise** your accounts

Attribution: "Cyclonis Password Manager." Cyclonis. Accessed April 23, 2018. https://www.cyclonis.com/products/password-manager/.